# Are there Spreadsheets (samples) with Google Apps script to work with CiviCRM?

Tags: google, custom

Has anyone heard of some CiviCRM contact or data import tools made with Google Spreadsheets / Google Apps Scripts that can be customized for specific use?

I do a lot of various semi-automatic data processing in spreadsheets and creating proper CSVs every time is a challenge.

Answer (score 4):

[Here's an example](https://topaz.github.io/paste/#XQAAAQC/DgAAAAAAAAAzHUn/qWH7EwabHnyheoyXMg+IWM4H8V2qoSHM4Y7CMH5GdBUvc6Z2TDt7JfE3zATUT1RT0yfdT6fz+ijncueOsVVKoDJp+CulJdHbSdYQjbPruZiVBD0ZxG8l4C2sIkxgJc1YqKxTVUDeHAQr9ZSBTnJ2xhPcPAwjJnUsM4VTElZ3+KCl+rFffft1EXbOwIc3KQ2uDMlP3HT9avEuN/2yZeaep0zimLXDr8Nl6pYZ1Hfc6N0yuc5OLnMRqvX+Rx/YPm7MIkO5UBNxSDLcFUbH2auUcpjIv/Au2iEEOi9vVRTdqU5RFiVxzCeJxvg3OXo9yUEbh/KAYz4JDqp/G64VP529f8qtrBaDVKu5DxRMmad/RpZgAqazQp1IAjT69ovQH7QFLWcB9+50i1nFkJMtUKqHz3Lxn1qTuPTTTk1lOtNb9dv0vm5FuarcXdY5Rcnuw3cWMaFcb+8GaJu6ARGpka7QAQVv/RAE1Td9odLIJ23Sr51628qIv76OucdJZ9O6i8QeYx2067Adm+KRYBQl9gYHfe248ZDOhP+QIH0quWPWMaKhgj7RTrd/x6bigWi9B9e0F8mVM0w4O1BygiOEYoWbZfoFOWt8197AqQQdGn+hJ8bN/IyWTkOUFz7TQZ+3QPoS2Jum5dbldLQl/gwYx977D8Ytzxig1iIa+FcfoVUDE+/tP+I3P/ZzQN48SMxfMZP9gnYtyPRsPrsyLx4lhUpEbfZ9KrUITUAGAlec0jLjMk4KacLas+gg+vjYMeDi4YX9RX9F5TOqzxC7r4i2avRmGRt8sREGmw/wY23KQv76wUDp2CwXdwT/skmJJ/uAfTGp+CKHS8o2ocHkMS1wea+9VGKYc/5MUlGahNSBdZklNbkrf7R/30Z+UNoQilxd+QFUEmT2sKlpbalBqsYJBf9F+gRAaFxCDPvZskzI5Gy42kOwGS/rN/hEW9kLZMlzGWWCrWyGnXQKqy26GyPoHwwtuE5yeW5RxndSPg3nTugdGpAULnQhehB1tq8rNzeioLWQ9WKMJf4TDaC25uI1s6AEuNHt3PRO5NJSDf0puNGit/yLVnQih3HhDjWRDZXguc+OQoWyNJSAWUl6KtyFxBbE27ckDMNcjkfPGplQe0xoTDSi95ayCaq39x89OQ0q9wUEsMciVRhlUjg6EhZKbseUQjK2slQejOQw9Jq1D+1vQUL25A1dCLCjlABoanSrQrxnNw++PEw28gFPQ3yPxoCoQ4aC4xVRuioNK4o3kVrQwfGlntH3l75SdG7hu0m0ZUIdrzhdWvA9FjQvtbBztcOccBNRJopBkBFFoqdeCNoapJ5LofStnAH0Qp1HemDspSsQFvz6ji3cyPa7jfaToQYWf3vJb31HpzxBwOKDUkLlyllZ3woCUO0zR80X45zUAshUDxpi5jXbfLbqJclNADdGtkK3qu9S/CFS+g4mTVsJ9BoV1knULNasV1aJb7GcdfvAusVYI3EZzHWrva1eEJIyiu6MtBp+8bgbSebffrj/77R7sTyy/zrcQ5kUz2VA8vKIxfQkIfnd19uyce16M2b2qUvU6Ek2ki+ZC3bXbLtDR75ukch8jTzVzRCxO+8dpGcBCGkzyk8rWJk6hhRBIx1gRvFvq2VgM+loywFsqYF2iU2yGUb7QLZKimwJR1Uq3lSwSdggR0SjGjU2db54qrJPUURW8YBgavXovf7gmaLQ/rO1hCyue5F35WEZaS4NXJXRhUwbaPp9ww973WUhedJzQqgzDmS0sEedZ5AAC8ez9hsOj44uVwzxnqlYZv1NiXAxuMl+nXFQ2MHREYS9GluAOYCQATTC8Gr4LLIIrHhWCbvqhNwHxJk35r4m1ix3fs4y9xjIS4rrsHlYF0iXlrHzfX5WnQ2YXeMQCrmd0KRYgcfAI7rj1CBzyyitn6O8TgWeEheknwB5ih+I+8p9l/PaC2kRE9O2Z1HONG0P7lJHvZC+LA+8zuChZPqSXFl2HQGJO/BSd4/dCPmHo2IDEDEYzfmM4bYSRnL06yD2oH3qydDG6SY+6QBv3MnoyWdN/O5QGEYad29XKGboStHu8swmIjfA+y28aFp4bZN4GMS7SuE9FqjfFhxKtAW+XYkxJ0nRHvWam1ALUQfGNmgyzmASrnakXrVEduZ4c5WXJ/a+cW8x4EEyOqGys0ISXMTFPpCXiop176MwBsRbFISv1ygV1nnTvFb4EbwmLOfEf0cWmBe4Gx+Ht+KHZcQSDnwd+JEYTeSLD8tqlrKyD/gKKVnmK5AoIdXLJZmCBFv/7RbbdQ==). We have a WP-hosted Civi install using the v3 API. This pulls contact records from some smart groups and dumps the entries as a table in a google sheet. Other pages on that sheet automatically parse/filter the data table. I'm a novice coder, so perhaps clunky, but it will give you the guts of the API calls and sheet filling.